# Add custom attributes in mailchimp list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp

Is there any way in mailchimp to  add custom attribute in list with help of Api while creating list or after creating list.I am using mailchimp v2 and Gibbon Gem for mailchimp integration

Comment: I tried to figure out what you mean but since you use different terms than mail chimp I actually have no idea!

Comment: I am creating list with mailchimp api and looking if there is way so that i can create list with custom fields

Comment: As far as I see you can only pass those parameters http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/

Comment: https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/merge-var-add.php

Comment: In this link there is a way how to add custom field in list with API but i am not able to integrate with my app

Comment: Great, so now I know what you're talking about! If you search https://github.com/amro/gibbon/tree/api_v2 for `merge` there are examples as far as I see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100962/discussion-between-goyalsachin52-and-michal-szyndel).

Comment: With help of this gem we can only use FNAME and LNAME while adding subscriber in list but i need custom field.

Comment: Did you try adding other ones? Are you sure the gem doesn't support it?

Comment: Yes first we need to add field to list then it work else not bcoz FNAME and LNAME are default available in list